# How to make a kernel module use a function from another kernel module?

Tags: linux, module, kernel, raspberry-pi, driver

I'm building a kernel module in order to create a gamepad using raspberry pi GPIO. I'm using an ADC converter (MCP3008) to convert joystick analog entries in digital values. I've seen that the kernel [mcp320x.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/iio/adc/mcp320x.c) is already existing and I'd like to use it to read the values.

So my question is quite simple, how do I use mcp320x.c function to use it in my own kernel module ?

Multiple sources use EXPORT_SYMBOL, but to do this I have to modify the "official" driver (and may cause issues from updates).

Do you have any solution the may work ? Thank in advance :)

Comment: Usually in that case driver has to be split to *core*, *glu driver 1*, and *glue driver 2* parts. Consider *drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-designware\** for example.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer. Do you have any *simple* examples ? Thank you very much

Comment: Answer to these questions: 1) what bus the ADC chip is connected to? 2) what kind of functions you need and why? Because at the end it might be that you have SPI connected chip (which that driver was written for) and you actually don't need anything in kernel since userspace can communicate to the chip via IIO interface (if there is one).

Comment: 1) ADC is connected to SPI bus 2) In need to read the adc values to convert them in my driver (which create a joypad). If i'm not wrong, i can't create joypad from userspace, and then i can't use these fonction. That's why i search an easy way to read value from adc, since i've seen the already existing driver i though i could use it in my driver